# Установить rustup в linux

Tags: rust

в командной строке работает `rustc`, и работает `cargo`

Но не работает `rustup` и вообще не вижу ни мануалов ни ответов как его установить.

Если что, команду `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh` запускал

Подскажите. Спасибо

Comment: Не особо подходящий для SO формат вопроса. Лучше спроси в http://forum.rustycrate.ru | https://gitter.im/ruRust/easy | https://t.me/rust_beginners_ru .

Comment: В каком именно linux? И как вы добились работоспособности rustc и cargo?

Comment: Какой вывод команды curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh ?